# Imgur API get max number of pages for given tag (JS)

Tags: javascript, json, imgur

I'm using the current Imgur API (v3) to build a random image function using JavaScript. Selecting an image isn't the problem but choosing a upper limit for a tag is. A tag could be anything and is usualy represented as https://api.imgur.com/3/t/kittens/1
whereas the last 1 in this endpoint is the page.

Requesting this link or without it the page number on the end returns a total_itemsof 1248 by 60 items per page.

My function chooses a page between 1 and a tags upper limit.
This upper limit is set by me, manually.
The problem is that a item could contain an album and therefore could possible have more than one image. Which means I can't calculate the upper limit doing: total_items / 60.

Has anonye worked with this API and could give some advice?